# What can cause duplicated XML sitemap links?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I have a site where I have [XML Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) installed.  I was using node-based sitemaps, and everything was working fine.  I also enabled the menu sub-module, and now I see duplicate links for all of my content:

[image: screenshot]

What can cause this?

Comment: Added more info, please help.

Comment: This is a valid question. It's because you have both XML node and XML menu enabled. You are seeing them twice because that content is both a node and included in a menu. You need to just enable one or the other. XML site map isn't smart enough to remove duplicates. However if you have XML node turned on you have no reason to have menu on anyways.

Comment: @NigelWaters I have never seen duplicated links when both the node and menu submodules are enabled (I just double checked it on my site).  There are good reasons to have both enabled.  You may have non-node menu entries that you want indexed, and you may have nodes that don't exist in menus that you want indexed.  In this particular case, though, I think the issue may have to do with character encoding.

Comment: Interesting. You make a valid point. However in my installations this is indeed the case. When you have both enabled you get duplicates.

Comment: I also add non node entries using the XML custom links submodule

Comment: Hey u guys, it seems to me that in the day and a half that i had this duplication, many of my Google search appearances where temporarily hidden, and only when i remove this duplication (by safely removing the XML sitemap menu" component) where my appearances showed up again...

Comment: @NigelWaters This is a very weird situation.  I reopened the question. I checked another site, and saw no dups.  On a third site, I did see dups.  The difference was that the third site has Locale and i18n enabled (though not the XML i18n module).

Answer (score 2):

Please visit the feature request about "[Remove duplicate links when using both menu and node sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257191)". It has a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/xmlsitemap-2257191-2.patch) which works fine.